# where to place images upload directory on a gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am using gradle and I have the default folder structure set by IntelliJ.

I am wondering where should I place an images `uploads` folder in this folder structure so that I can use it for running and testing?

I am thinking that it has something to do with gradle configuration file.

Comment: I'm interested in storing images inside that folder.

Comment: What's the nature of your application: Web, console? Gradle and/or Maven will give you a (quite common) but slightly different directory structure for those app types.

Comment: Can I assume that these images are going to be accessed as resources?

Comment: Yes... Something like `http://.../uploads/images/ca827808-733d-4252-b09a-3007a4debd5d.png`. The path to image is stored in DB.